# Unable to Log with Admin Profile in Dev Org

Tags: profile

I have different Dev Orgs for my R&D - Facing problems with one of my Dev Orgs -I had created 2 profiles - One with Standard profile and the other with System Admin Profile. I am logging in after a year now, and I see that when I log in with my credentials, it automatically logs me in as the with the Standard Sales Profile because of which Iam unable to even "VIEW" Dashboards - I get an Insufficient privileges" message. How can I log in as the System Admin and take control of the Org?. Help appreciated.Recording of the Org given below. If this cannot be resolved, I still have other Active Developer Orgs where I can continue my R&D but since this Org is also my baby appreciate if someone help me crack this problem...
https://www.facebook.com/groups/1389712651350452/permalink/1756718421316538/

Comment: You need to figure out the correct username and password. Those are your only options unless the standard user has some admin pro leagues assigned via perm sets

Comment: It Worked!!!! Thank you@Eric. I can now login as Admin and have access to my Dashboards!!!